# Why can't tokio::spawn be refactored into a separate function?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I setup a daisy-chain of broadcast channels and send to the first and receive a notification from the last. Each created forwarder has a task created which loops awaiting recv to complete. It is all working. However, I'd like to refactor the task creation out of where it is into a fn and I seem to be running afoul of some async rules, which I've been unable to overcome.

I use the following crates:

```toml
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "0.3", features = ["full"] }
async-trait = "0.1.42"
```

Here's the code, if you'd prefer to examine it here:

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::fmt;

use async_trait::async_trait;
use tokio::sync::broadcast;
use tokio::spawn;
use tokio::sync::Mutex;
use tokio::runtime;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let rt  = runtime::Runtime::new()?;

    let mut tasks = Vec::new();
    let mut first = None;
    let mut prev = None;
    rt.block_on(async {
        // setup a daisy-chain of 5 machines
        for id in 1..=5 {
            // create sender and adapter wrapping forwarder
            let (_, s, mut a) = build_bounded(Forwarder::new(id), 100);
            // create a task to run the recv loop -- consider using stream
```

I'd like to pull this spawn out into a fn that returns the task.

```
            // why can't this be refactored into a fn that returns task?
            let task = spawn(async move {
                loop {
                    let cmd = a.receiver.recv().await;
                    if cmd.is_ok() {
                        a.machine.recv(cmd.unwrap()).await;
                    } else {
                        break
                    }
                }
                a.machine.disconnected().await;
            });

            // save the task
            tasks.push(task);

            if prev.is_none() {
                // first time save the sender
                first = Some(s.clone());
            } else {
                // tell previous sender to send to this sender
                send_cmd(prev.unwrap(), TestMessage::AddSender(s.clone()));
            }
            prev = Some(s);
        }
        // create notifier and tell the last to send to it
        let (s, mut r) = broadcast::channel::<TestMessage>(10);
        send_cmd(prev.unwrap(), TestMessage::Notify(s, 1));
        // send to the first
        send_cmd(first.unwrap(), TestMessage::TestData(0));
        // wait for the notification
        if let Ok(_msg) = r.recv().await {
            println!("got notification");
        }
        println!("done");
    });
    Ok(())
}

#[async_trait]
pub trait Machine<T>: Send + Sync + 'static {
    async fn disconnected(&self);
    async fn recv(&self, cmd: T);
}

pub trait InstructionSet: Clone {
    type InstructionSet;
}

fn send_cmd<T: Send + Sync + 'static>(sender: broadcast::Sender<T>, cmd: T) {
    if sender.send(cmd).is_err() {}
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub enum TestMessage {
    // TestData has a single parameter, as a tuple
    TestData(usize),
    // AddSender can be implemented to push a sender onto a list of senders
    AddSender(TestMessageSender),
    // Notify, is setup for a notification via TestData, where usize is a message count
    Notify(TestMessageSender, usize),
}

// TestMessageSender is shorthand for a sender of a TestMessage instruction.
pub type TestMessageSender = broadcast::Sender<TestMessage>;

impl InstructionSet for TestMessage {
    type InstructionSet = TestMessage;
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct Forwarder {
    /// a id, mosly used for logging
    id: usize,
    /// The mutable bits...
    mutable: Mutex<ForwarderMutable>,
}
/// This is the mutable part of the Forwarder
pub struct ForwarderMutable {
    /// collection of senders, each will be sent any received message.
    senders: Vec<TestMessageSender>,
    /// received_count is the count of messages received by this forwarder.
    received_count: usize,
    /// send_count is the count of messages sent by this forwarder.
    send_count: usize,
    /// notify_count is compared against received_count for means of notifcation.
    notify_count: usize,
    /// notify_sender is sent a TestData message with the data being the number of messages received.
    notify_sender: Option<TestMessageSender>,
    /// forwarding multiplier
    forwarding_multiplier: usize,
    // for TestData, this is the next in sequence
    next_seq: usize,
}
impl Default for ForwarderMutable {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self::new()
    }
}
impl ForwarderMutable {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            senders: Vec::<TestMessageSender>::new(),
            received_count: 0,
            send_count: 0,
            notify_count: 0,
            notify_sender: None,
            forwarding_multiplier: 1,
            next_seq: 0,
        }
    }
    fn drop_all_senders(&mut self) {
        self.senders.clear();
        self.notify_sender = None;
    }

    /// if msg is TestData, validate the sequence or reset if 0
    fn validate_sequence(&mut self, msg: TestMessage) -> Result<TestMessage, TestMessage> {
        match msg {
            TestMessage::TestData(seq) if seq == self.next_seq => self.next_seq += 1,
            TestMessage::TestData(seq) if seq == 0 => self.next_seq = 1,
            TestMessage::TestData(_) => return Err(msg),
            _ => (),
        }
        // bump received count
        self.received_count += 1;
        Ok(msg)
    }

    /// If msg is a configuration msg, handle it otherwise return it as an error
    fn handle_config(&mut self, msg: TestMessage, id: usize) -> Result<(), TestMessage> {
        match msg {
            TestMessage::Notify(sender, on_receive_count) => {
                println!("forwarder {}: added notifier", id);
                self.notify_sender = Some(sender);
                self.notify_count = on_receive_count;
            },
            TestMessage::AddSender(sender) => {
                println!("forwarder {}: added sender", id);
                self.senders.push(sender);
            },
            msg => return Err(msg),
        }
        Ok(())
    }

    /// handle the action messages
    fn handle_action(&mut self, message: TestMessage, id: usize) {
        match message {
            TestMessage::TestData(_) => {
                println!("forwarder {}: received TestData", id);
                for sender in &self.senders {
                    for _ in 0 .. self.forwarding_multiplier {
                        send_cmd(sender.clone(), TestMessage::TestData(self.send_count));
                        self.send_count += 1;
                    }
                }
            },
            _ => self.senders.iter().for_each(|sender| {
                for _ in 0 .. self.forwarding_multiplier {
                    send_cmd(sender.clone(), message.clone());
                }
            }),
        }
    }

    /// handle sending out a notification and resetting counters when notificaiton is sent
    fn handle_notification(&mut self, id: usize) {
        if self.received_count == self.notify_count {
            let count = self.get_and_clear_received_count();
            if let Some(notifier) = self.notify_sender.as_ref() {
                println!("forwarder {}: sending notification", id);
                send_cmd(notifier.clone(), TestMessage::TestData(count));
            }
        }
    }

    /// get the current received count and clear counters
    fn get_and_clear_received_count(&mut self) -> usize {
        let received_count = self.received_count;
        self.received_count = 0;
        self.send_count = 0;
        received_count
    }
}

impl Forwarder {
    pub fn new(id: usize) -> Self { Self { id, ..Default::default() } }
    pub const fn get_id(&self) -> usize { self.id }
}

#[async_trait]
impl Machine<TestMessage> for Forwarder {
    async fn disconnected(&self) {
        println!("forwarder {}: disconnected", self.get_id());
        // drop senders
        let mut mutable = self.mutable.lock().await;
        mutable.drop_all_senders();
    }

    async fn recv(&self, message: TestMessage) {
        let mut mutable = self.mutable.lock().await;
        match mutable.handle_config(message, self.get_id()) {
            Ok(_) => (),
            Err(msg) => match mutable.validate_sequence(msg) {
                Ok(msg) => {
                    mutable.handle_action(msg, self.get_id());
                    mutable.handle_notification(self.get_id());
                },
                Err(msg) => panic!("sequence error fwd {}, msg {:#?}", self.get_id(), msg),
            },
        }    
    }
}

struct Adapter<T: InstructionSet<InstructionSet = T>> {
    sender: broadcast::Sender<T>,
    pub receiver: broadcast::Receiver<T>,
    pub machine: Arc<dyn Machine<<T as InstructionSet>::InstructionSet>>,
}

impl<T: InstructionSet<InstructionSet = T>> Clone for Adapter<T> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        Self {
            sender: self.sender.clone(),
            receiver:  self.sender.subscribe(),
            machine: self.machine.clone(),
        }
    }
}

fn build_bounded<T, U>(raw: U, capacity: usize) -> (Arc<U>, broadcast::Sender<T>, Adapter<T>)
where
    U: Machine<T> + Send + Sync + 'static,
    T: InstructionSet<InstructionSet = T>,
{
    let instance = Arc::new(raw);
    let (sender, receiver) = broadcast::channel::<T>(capacity);
    let cloned_sender = sender.clone();
    let machine = instance.clone() as Arc<dyn Machine<T>>;
    let adapter = Adapter::<T> { sender, receiver, machine, };
    (instance, cloned_sender, adapter)
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
pub struct Error {
    message: String,
}


impl fmt::Display for Error {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> Result<(), fmt::Error> {
        write!(f, "{}", self.message)
    }
}
```

Apologies for the large example, the relevant bits are at the top. I included it all so that the curious can easily drop into their favorite thing. Here's a [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1554f0e26c61f792f6b6a499d2581e58).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refactor that snippet into a standalone function, but the generic type needed for the Adapter argument needs to have additional trait bounds to comply with Tokio's spawn requirements.  This is inferred for you when it is inline, but when pulled out into a function it must be explicit.

All task functions spawned by Tokio need to be `Send` as well as `'static`. Note that static here just means that it is allowable for the annotated type to live until the end of the program. It is unrelated to static as applied to a reference.
An in-depth discussion of this subtlety is provided in the Tokio spawning tutorial: https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial/spawning - look for a section halfway through discussing the 'static and Send bounds.

Here is the result of the refactor:

```
fn spawn_task<T>(mut a: Adapter<T>) -> JoinHandle<()>
where
    T: InstructionSet<InstructionSet = T> + Send + 'static
{
    spawn(async move {
        loop {
            let cmd = a.receiver.recv().await;
            if cmd.is_ok() {
                a.machine.recv(cmd.unwrap()).await;
            } else {
                break
            }
        }
        a.machine.disconnected().await;
    })
}
```

Playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bb42d4b22f053a56836a74400a50f0e1